# Serialization: XmlRoot Element Name defined in abstract class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm serializing XML (using `System.Xml.Serialization`) output for an API project and want that all responses have a root element of `Response`

I have a `ResponseModelBase` class that I hoped to handle this in:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Response")]
public abstract class ResponseModelBase
{
    // other common stuff
}
```

Then I use a concrete class:

```
public class CustomerPostResponseModel : ResponseModelBase
{
    // other stuff here
}
```

With this setup, when I return the concrete class the XML root is `CustomerPostResponseModel`, where I want it to be `Response`.

I can "fix" this by applying the `XmlRoot` attribute to the concrete class, but would much prefer to specify this at the abstract level.

Is there a way I can do that?  Thanks

Comment: Did you work this out?